# Is it possible to create a program that can redirect folder icon directory depending on the file location?

Tags: c#, vb.net

**Background**

Yo, guys. So first off, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcDbA.jpg) is an anime folder that displays all my anime series with different folder icons. All of the said custom icons are located in a hidden folder named "icons". This format is what I've laid out in other folders of their corresponding years.

**Problem/Situation**

As we all know, when we move/tamper the "icons" folder or the directory of the anime folder, the link gets broken and the custom icons of the anime series disappear. This problem can be remedied by either assigning the custom icons again or renaming the directory.

I tend to copy anime folders to other hard drives. What I want to know if it's possible to create a program that automatically fixes the directory link of the anime folder depending on the location it's in.

For example, let's say I copy the 2018 anime folder from directory "G:\2018" and place it in Desktop. The custom folder icon of, let's say, Slow Start is still G:\2018\icons\Slow_Start_Folder_Icon.ico. The program, when run, will automatically change the directory link to C:\Users****\Desktop\2018\icons\Slow_Start_Folder_Icon.ico. Of course, simultaneously with the other anime folders.

Any enlightening answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance also.

**UPDATE 3:** This is my current working code, with ideas and advice gotten from @Jimi. Tested and it worked for me.

```
private static void UpdateIcons() //for updating folder icons to new directory
    {
        int start, end;
        string filedir = Environment.CurrentDirectory, olddir = null, newdir = null;

        IEnumerable<string> Ini = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filedir, "desktop.ini", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string deskini in Ini)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(deskini, FileAttributes.Archive);

            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(deskini))
            {
                if (line.Contains("IconResource"))
                {
                    start = line.IndexOf("icons");

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Length.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(line.IndexOf("icons").ToString());

                    if (line.Contains(","))
                    {
                        end = line.IndexOf(",");

                        olddir = line.Substring(start, (end - start));

                        Console.Write(end - start);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        end = line.Length - 1;

                        Console.Write(end);

                        olddir = line.Substring(start, (end - start + 1));

                        Console.Write(end - start);
                    }


                    newdir = File.ReadAllText(deskini);

                    newdir = newdir.Replace(line, "IconResource=" + filedir + "\\" + olddir);

                    File.WriteAllText(deskini, newdir, Encoding.Unicode);

                    Console.WriteLine(olddir);
                    Console.WriteLine(newdir);

                }

            }

            File.SetAttributes(deskini, FileAttributes.Hidden);

        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9331/Create-Icons-for-Folders-in-Windows-Explorer-Using

Comment: Isn't it written in the `desktop.ini` hidden file inside the same folder?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, it is. But, I want a program that when run, overwrites ALL of the desktop.ini icon resource into the current directory they're housed in as an example above. I don't know if it can be done, or how.

Comment: Well, why not? Use [Directory.EnumerateFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)) with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to get all the `desktop.ini` files in the path, then edit the `IconResource=` reference (when there's one), setting it to the new file path.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry in advance because of my inexperience. So I use, let's say, C# in Visual Studio, and write down the code that you said right? Are there any references on how to do that?

Comment: Start with `IEnumerable<string> IniFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"[Your Folder Path]", "desktop.ini", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` then `foreach (string DesktopIni in IniFiles) { ... }`. Since it's a Hidden files, before editing its content, set the Archive attribute: `File.SetAttributes(DesktopIni, FileAttributes.Archive);` read the file content. If the second line contains "IconResource=", set it to the new path, save the file. Set the Hidden attribute back: `File.SetAttributes(DesktopIni, FileAttributes.Hidden);`. Post your best shot at it here, editing your question, if you need help

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the help. Sadly, I need to re-install Visual Studio again. I'll try to work on what you said when I have time. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jimi Holy shit, it's been so long thanks to college and Thesis. If you don't mind again, what should I use for Visual Studio C#? Is it a Blank App or Console App? From what I'm imagining, the program will run when double- clicked, and proceed to do the necessary things above.

Comment: @Jimi I have edited the post. If you don't mind, I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I'll give it a look as soon I have some free time.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you.

Comment: The best way to thank @Jimi is to mark his answer as the answer, below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application accepts a command line parameter, where the Icons repository (a folder name) can be specified. If none is provided, it assumes the Icons repository is named "icons", found in the current executing path.

[Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) is used to determine the executable path. The `Location` property returns a standard-formatted Path.

[Directory.GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) is used to get the directory listing, including the SubDirectories, of the directories in the current path. The current path and the icons directory is then excluded from the list, since those Folders are not subject to customization.

[Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) is the use to build the list of the icons files contained in the Icons folder.

To update the Folders customization (Explorer can be somewhat *lazy* when it comes to update these changes: it uses the `IconCache.db` storage when not otherwise instructed) we PInvoke [SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetsetfoldercustomsettings).
This Shell API creates or updates the `desktop.ini` file, located inside each customized folder. This file references the Icon used as the Folder Custom Icon.
This function allows a swift update of the folder new aspect. The update is, in this case, immediate. No need to delete the icons cache or restart Explorer.

**Related informations:**
[How to Customize Folders with Desktop.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini)
This document is part of [The Windows Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell-entry) document, *The Book* of Shell operations.
An old definition of [`SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb759797(v=vs.94)?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is missing in the official documentation.

Compile this code as `Release` and copy the exeutable in the upper level folder where the customized sub folders are listed.

**NOTE:**
In this example, I'm randomly picking the Icon to assign to a folder from the Icons repository (using a `Random` value). You need define your own logic to assign the *right* icon to a specific Folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public enum FolderCustomSettingsMask : uint
{
    InfoTip = 0x00000004,
    Clsid = 0x00000008,
    IconFile = 0x00000010,
    Logo = 0x00000020,
    Flags = 0x00000040
}

public enum FolderCustomSettingsRW : uint
{
    Read = 0x00000001,
    ForceWrite = 0x00000002,
    ReadWrite = Read | ForceWrite
}

[SecurityCritical]
[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(ref SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS pfcs, string pszPath, FolderCustomSettingsRW dwReadWrite);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS
{
    public uint dwSize;
    public FolderCustomSettingsMask dwMask;
    public IntPtr pvid;
    public string pszWebViewTemplate;
    public uint cchWebViewTemplate;
    public string pszWebViewTemplateVersion;
    public string pszInfoTip;
    public uint cchInfoTip;
    public IntPtr pclsid;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public string pszIconFile;
    public uint cchIconFile;
    public int iIconIndex;
    public string pszLogo;
    public uint cchLogo;
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string CurrentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string IconsFolder = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : Path.Combine(CurrentPath, @"icons");
    UpdateFolderIcons(CurrentPath, IconsFolder);

    Console.WriteLine($"Press any key to terminate...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}


[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static void UpdateFolderIcons(string BaseFolder, string IconsFolder)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current path: {BaseFolder}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing...");
    Console.WriteLine();

    List<string> ExcludeDirList = new List<string>() {BaseFolder, IconsFolder};
    List<string> DirList = Directory.GetDirectories(BaseFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    DirList = DirList.Except(ExcludeDirList).ToList();

    if (DirList.Count == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine($"No directories found!");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{DirList.Count} Directories found");
    Console.WriteLine("Updating...");
    Console.WriteLine();

    int UpdateCount = 0;
    List<string> IconNames = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(BaseFolder, IconsFolder), "*").ToList();
    if (IconNames.Count == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine($"No icons found in {IconsFolder}");
        return;
    }

    foreach (string sPath in DirList)
    {
        string IconName = IconNames[random.Next(0, IconNames.Count)];

        SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS FolderSettings = new SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS  {
            dwMask = FolderCustomSettingsMask.IconFile,
            pszIconFile = IconName,
            iIconIndex = 0
        };

        uint hResult = SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(
            ref FolderSettings, sPath + char.MinValue, FolderCustomSettingsRW.ForceWrite);
        UpdateCount += 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{UpdateCount} Files Updated");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, although I have some clarifications and problems. Firstly, I recently changed the name of the icons folder to "icons+year_of_parent_folder." 
Secondly, while testing your code, the program automatically ran without giving me time to input the folder path.
Thirdly, due to the nature of my problem, I was thinking that my program should only replace the **first words** of the Icon Resource path directory before "icons_ folder_name." e.g. G:\2017\icons2017\fate stay night heaven's feel.ico => C:\Users****\Desktop\2018\icons2017\fate stay night heaven's feel.ico.

Comment: Format of my folders and icons are like this: https://imgur.com/a/0EvFdWf

Comment: I am revising my tested code with your suggestions. I'll update my code in a while. :)

Comment: @N. Tanaka  This is a Console program. If you want to pass an argument to it, pass if in the command line: open a console (cmd.exe) in the top folder path, write `MyProgram.exe argument` (i.e., `myprogram.exe "icons2018"`. As it is, the code takes the **icon name** found in the `desktop.ini` and substitutes the old path with the current path. If you want it more *interactive*, you could modify it to accept an input at run-time, where you can manually specify the *icons* folder.

Comment: I see, I was doing it wrong. Thanks for all the help, dude.

Comment: Yo, dude. It's been a long time. Mainly, because I'm a lazy bum. Anyways, I finished the program that I wanted thanks to your help. Although, a small problem:

I've noticed that, although the folder properties it has an icon already, it [doesn't reflect](https://imgur.com/a/oM3JLqH) with the folder itself. Of course, this was implemented programmaticaly. And I waited for 2 hrs as of this writing.

Any ideas? If you don't mind me asking. Thank you.

Comment: @N. Tanaka  Folder icons (as, actually, all link-style icons) are cached. The folder icons are updated when explorer acknowledges the change or the cache is refreshed. If you never change directory, the folder cache is never updated. You might have noticed, when you install a new program, that the Desktop is refreshed at some point, making the Icons *blink* a couple of time. That is the caused by the installer, which tries to update the new shell link's Icon created for the program, if any. Sometime, just re-reading the folder structure can cause a cache update.

Comment: Oh, and I know it takes a while. But, exactly how long? Cuz it's taking a long time. And for clarification, the above referenced link is a result of my program CREATING a new desktop.ini file since the anime folder originally never had one.

Comment: Sorry for double commenting. I think I myself am lagging. So, based on what you said, is there a way to refresh the cache programmatically in c#? Based on my testing with my program, the icons are automatically reflected IF *the existing IconResource value is changed or updated.* If i created it programmatically, as I mentioned above, it's not automatically reflected. Do I just wait?

Comment: @N. Tanaka  There are different ways to cause a refresh of the icon cache. You could use [SHChangeNotify](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify) or [SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetsetfoldercustomsettings). The latter will probably have faster results, when used per-directory (setting new CustomSettings values for each Directory in the path). Using the former, the notifications are delayed. More if an Explorer window is opened in the folders path).

Comment: @N. Tanaka   Note that `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` creates a `desktop.ini` file on its own. You wouldn't need to update the file yourself. Well, it could also cause a race problem. Maybe I'll update the current code to show how it is used, if you think it could be useful.

Comment: @N. Tanaka  Well, I've already updated the code. The new Icons should be visible immediately now.

Comment: HOLY SHIT IT WORKED THANKS A LOT DUDE. I used some of your code and modified it to fit my program. IT WORKED HAHAHAHA

Although a small problem though:

Other properties such as [ViewState], Mode=, Vid=, and FolderType=Videos are not included/erased in the creation/update of desktop.ini. Is it needed for the folder itself or no?

Comment: And lastly, is there a way to bypass folders which require higher permissions? My workaround is running the exe as admin  but folders such as System Volume Information denies the program and ends it with the exception. I usually just run it within my anime folders to effect the icons which is just a very minor problem.

But for the sake of it, is there a way to bypass said permissions? From my research, C# doesn't have a way to just ignore exceptions and just continue with it. Although, I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, and how do I set the Encoding of the desktop.ini to Unicode, and the FileAttributes of said desktop.ini back to Hidden? Or does your program render the aforementioned unnecessary?

Comment: @N. Tanaka  The first two point are not really related to this question, the second being a very broad matter. 3) The Encoding is set to the DefaultEncoding of the system where the function is run. 4) The function already sets the Hidded attribute of the file.

Comment: I see. Sorry for asking the unrelated questions. I have created the program I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @N. Tanaka   Nothing to be sorry about. You just need to ask another (new) question :)